# How to get started with Bibliographies

Tags: bibliographies, learning

**Background**

Although I've been using LaTeX for over ten years, I've never really got to grips with the organisation and typesetting of bibliographies, but I've just been handed an incentive, so it's time to learn. I already have specific, detailed questions, but I honestly think that I should try at least to help myself with the basics before asking here.

I am aware of the questions [biblatex in a nutshell (for beginners)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13509/biblatex-for-idiots) and [What to do to switch to biblatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5091/what-to-do-to-switch-to-biblatex), but they don't, I think, give me the answers I need.

**Environment**

I run TeXLive on Windows 7, with a tendency towards XeLaTeX and latexmk. My extensive use of `memoir` might influence things, and I'd like to know if and how. At this stage, RefWorks, Mendeley, and Zotero ''have come up in conversation with no lawyers present'', and any observations on that would be interesting, although I don't think that bibliographic database integration is a major issue.

---

I forgot to mention that I'm trying to migrate all of my typesetting to UTF-8, though for bibliographies I can get by for the moment with the character set corresponding to ISO-Latin-1. Later, I **may** need Turkish (e.g. ş) and Welsh (e.g. ŵ)

I also forgot to mention that my editors are(!) TeXWorks, Notepad++, and, recently, Kile. Please try to avoid anything involving vi or emacs, as I've tried four times to go down that path but am not bright enough...

---

**Questions**

1. As a complete bibliography newbie, what toolset should I use? As I   have no legacy bibliographic databases, my inclination is towards BibLaTeX and Biber, but I realise that may be a bit leading-edge, so I'd welcome any advice, especially on potential pitfalls.
2. What are useful reading and sample resources that I might read `to get started'?
3. What are the exact relationships between UTF-8 (Latin-1 subset), UTF-8 (Expanded beyond Latin-1 to include Turkish and Welsh), back-ends (bibtex.exe and biber.exe), and front-ends (biblatex.sty and, say, natbib.sty). Perhaps the best answer to this question would say which combinations don't work together?

Comment: On the biblatex vs bibtex question: [bibtex vs. biber and biblatex vs. natbib](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701/2693). Many non-Mac users here probably use [JabRef](http://jabref.sourceforge.net/) as their reference manager.

Comment: @Alan: Thanks, Alan. Sorry to hear about JabRef; I took a look at it yesterday, as it happens, and absolutely hated the UI... So I guess I'd better visit it again.

Comment: It would also be helpful to consider, and you probably already have, what you want out of it (e.g. entire or chapter/section bibliography, citations in text or footnotes, author index, ...), support for specific entry types and if there are specific output format  that you need (e.g. APA, MLA, publishers or journals with particular requirements, ...).

Comment: @Brent I'm not too impressed with the JabRef UI either, but I'm a spoiled Mac user who uses BibDesk.

Comment: @mas: That's absolutely correct, though I didn't want to bog us all down with too many detailed questions (and there are *lots*!) at this stage. One case, at least, requires a bastardized so-called 'Harvard' citation (parenthetical author-year) and bibliography style (with UPPERCASE NAMES, God help us), plus separate bibliography sections for {\cite}d and {\nocite}d. I think I'm going to ask everyone not to address these problems here, though, as I suspect they will be better as separate questions, later, when I'm not a complete Dummies in the subject.

Comment: @Brent.Longborough: See my answer for a quick comment on using the `harvard` citation commands. To typeset authors' names in the bibliography in all-uppercase (or is that small-caps?), the bib style file you use would need to contain the corresponding commands.

Comment: @Mico: Thanks. That was my first question to *them*: surely you mean small caps? 'Nooo,' was the answer, 'uppercase letters'. Why oh why is the world so full of crap?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You raise a lot of interesting questions and issues.

1. On the subject of `natbib/bibtex` vs `biblatex/biber`:

   If your bib entries

   - have a lot of letters with diacritics (umlauts) and other glyphs that aren't included in the basic ASCII set, or
   - use non-English but Latin-alphabet-based languages which employ special alphabetical ordering methods (e.g., in the Danish alphabet, `{\o}` comes *after* `z`), or
   - include entry types that were not included in the original design of bibtex (such as patents, CDs, videos, youtube clips, other content solely available on the www, to name but a few),

   then `biblatex` is definitely the way to go. (Actually, `bibtex8` does support UTF8 input, as @Herbert has kindly pointed out to me. However, as he also points out, UTF8 is only a subset of Unicode.)

   On the other hand, if your work does *not* involve such considerations, it's probably not necessary to incur the somewhat higher learning costs of the `biblatex` method over `natbib`/`bibtex`. (Oh well, I'm going to get a lot of complaints now from biblatex afficionados...) The [biblatex manual][1] is, unfortunately, not so much a user guide but a reference dictionary; the document does have a "User Guide" chapter, but it doesn't begin until page 43 and it's about as exciting a read as if you were to open a phone book on a randomly chosen page. Long on definitions, short on plot. :-(
2. Second, `bibtex` and `biber` are the "back-ends" which perform some heavy-duty work related to, say, sorting of entries. You'll need a "front-end" as well. For `biber`, the front-end is (of course) `biblatex`. For `bibtex`, there are quite a few front-end packages.

   - One of the most commonly used of these is `natbib`, which can operate in both "numerical" and "author-year" mode. A plus of `natbib` is great integration with the `hyperref` package -- a nontrivial point if you want to employ the latter package.
   - There's also the `harvard` citation package manager. If you choose to use that package and wish to use `hyperref` as well, be sure not to type `\usepackage{harvard}` in the preamble but, instead, to load both the `natbib` and `har2nat` packages. The `har2nat` package serves to map harvard-specific citation commands into equivalent `natbib` commands.
   - Even `biblatex` may be considered to be a front-end, albeit a particularly powerful one, for BibTeX.
3. Third, you need a "style file" to inform natbib/bibtex or biblatex/biber how to typeset both the citations in the text (e.g., whether to write "et al" or "and others" when truncating a list of authors) and the references in the bibliography text (e.g., typeset the full first and middle names of authors, or only the initials? italicize names of journals and titles of books?).

   - Again, there are any number of such style files around, and you'll have to decide which ones fit your specific needs. The learning cost involved in creating a bibtex style file from scratch is, unfortunately, *enormous*; fortunately, there is the `makebst.tex` utility program, created by the author of the the `natbib` package, which is mercifully entirely menu-driven and creates a .bst style file for you after you answer several dozen queries. (`makebst.tex` is included in most modern TeX distributions.)
   - If you're a `biblatex` user, the good news is that there are quite a few style-file packages around for use with `biblatex`.  E.g., there's `biblatex-chicago` and `biblatex-apa` if you want to conform to, say, the *Chicago Manual of Style* and *APA* methods. (Using one of these style files will spare you the drudgery of having to plow through the biblatex reference dictionary.)
4. Regarding your question what to read to get started with the LaTeX way(s) of creating bibliographies: I got my own start in this field by reading (and re-reading!) chapters 12 and 13, "Managing Citations" and "Bibliography Generation," of *The LaTeX Companion* (2nd ed.). A real user guide, not just a reference work. :-) This book is about 7 years old by now and hence doesn't discuss `biblatex` (since `biblatex` didn't exist back then). However, because biblatex builds on bibtex's basic approach (while aiming to overcome bibtex's many shortcomings), the two chapters contain lots of useful information for `biblatex` users as well.

Comment: Thanks, @Mico. I *am* finding the biblatex manual a bit heavy on my eyelids. I've updated the question to ask about the precise relationships between the front-ends, back-ends, and UTF8

Comment: Thanks again, for the addendum. My Companion has a big lump on bibliographies, bibtex, etc, but it's from 1994 (1st ed). I'll give it a more concentrated read...

Comment: @Mico Surely there are more than three major features even `biblatex+bibtex` offers that traditional `bibtex` can't. Compact, short and abbreviated citations and qualified citations lists are just a few. You might want to make it more clear that `biblatex` styles aren't driven by `bst` files. `biblatex` comes with many standard styles. Style packages like `biblatex-apa` and `biblatex-chicago` supplement these. Your comments on the manual aren't balanced IMO. Its first paragraph points the reader to selected sections and example `tex` files to get started.

Comment: @Audrey: I would certainly hope that my answer does *not* imply that there are *only* 3 areas in which biblatex improves on bibtex -- though I *do* claim that they are particularly relevant. Regarding my claim that the `biblatex` doc is not suitable as a user guide: I continue to stand by this view. I know that it states on page 1 that it is "a systematic reference manual" and hence that it does not *claim* to be a user guide. I  therefore wish that people wouldn't advise newbies to go read this document in order to learn how to use biblatex. Are they clueless, or are they practical jokers?

Comment: @Mico We'll have to disagree, then. I was a "newbie" not long ago. The example files from the documentation were enough to get me started. I did not read the user guide cover to cover, but selected sections were helpful.

Comment: @Audrey: I'm truly glad you're no longer a biblatex "newbie". Really! Would you be willing to claim that your experience with the biblatex documentation is the rule? Or, does your experience represent the exception to the rule?

Comment: @Mico How could I say either way? I'd probably need to poll users or something. But I am not particularly exceptional, so surely other people can learn. A distinction between using `biblatex` straight out of the box and rolling your own style should be made here. The former is easy. Having done the latter, I've learned to appreciate the manual much more.

Comment: @Audrey: I'm sorry, but I tend to agree with Mico. The biblatex manual points me, a quavering newbie, to nine different, disjoint sections. IMO, what it needs is a chapter called "Getting Started" which takes you through those nine bits in sequence, and outside a context of reference material. That isn't a complaint; I realise that the package authors are (a) very generous with their time already and (b) probably have real lives to get on with. Maybe when I'm less of a newbiw, I'll contribute this bit of writing...

Comment: I'll qualify that even further: "getting started" should only be a very small subset of the information given in those nine sections, which together are completely overpowering.

Comment: @Brent.Longborough No need to apologize. Having had a different experience with the documentation (and again this includes both the manual and the examples files), I wanted to weigh in on Mico's comments. A request for a short tour through those nine sections might make a good question for this site...

Comment: @Mico: `bibtex8` can handle `utf8`. It is better to say, that `bibtex` cannot handle unicode, because `utf8` refers to `inputenc` which is only a very limited subset of unicode

Comment: @Herbert - Thanks for this; I'll update my answer.