# Format a bib in IEEE style automatically

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, ieeetran, bibitem

I have a bib file where I put all my references. Now I want to write a new paper in IEEETran style (`\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}`).

I want to integerate my bib to be compatible with IEEE style. How can I do it please?

Note that in the template they use:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{00}
\bibitem{b1} bla bla
\end{thebibliography}
```

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "I have a bib file". Is it a file with all entries organized according to BibTeX syntax rules? If not, what exactly is in the file?

Comment: Could you consider using `biblatex-ieee`?

Comment: @Mico yes it is a file will all organized according to BibTeX syntax rules

Comment: Did you see the posting [How to get started with Bibliographies](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30825/5001)? Please familiarize yourself with the basics of creating formatted bibliographies, and formatted citation call-outs, with BibTeX (or biblatex/biber, if you prefer).

Comment: Note that they may not accept a separate `.bib` if the template specifies `thebibliography`.

Comment: Please let me know if my answer worked for you and if not why not.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 6):

If you plan to submit to the IEEE you should follow their recommendations if at all possible.

In particular **you should not use [`biblatex-ieee`](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-ieee) if you plan to submit to the IEEE**. That style is only intended for people who for some reason need to recreate the IEEE style for documents that are not submitted for IEEE publishing. See also https://github.com/josephwright/biblatex-ieee/pull/22#issuecomment-206542227

The [`IEEEtran` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/IEEEtran_HOWTO.pdf) has the following to say about bibliographies (p. 16, §XIII.C *Bibliographies*)

> Bibliographies  are most easily (and correctly) generated using the  `IEEEtran` BibTeX package [link to [How to Use the `IEEEtran` BibTeX Style](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/bibtex/IEEEtran_bst_HOWTO.pdf)] which is easily invoked via
>
> ```
> \bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
> \bibliography{IEEEabrv,mybibfile}
> ```
>
> See the `IEEEtran` BibTeX package  documentation  for  more information.
>   When submitting the document source (`.tex`) file to external parties,
>   it  is  strongly  recommended  that  the BibTeX `.bbl` file be manually copied into the document (within the traditional LaTeX bibliography  environment [`thebibliography`]) so as not to depend on external files to generate the  bibliography and to prevent the possibility of changes occurring therein.

You should definitely have a thorough look at the [`IEEEtran` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/IEEEtran_HOWTO.pdf) and the [`IEEEtran` BibTeX Style manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/bibtex/IEEEtran_bst_HOWTO.pdf) for more details and specific guidance.

Assuming your `.bib` file is called `IEEEexample.bib`, you could use

```
\documentclass[american]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}

\begin{document}
\cite{IEEEexample:article_typical}

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{IEEEabrv,IEEEexample}
\end{document}
```

You would compile that file normally with LaTeX, BibTeX, LaTeX, LaTeX, see [Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864)

Once you are done and want to submit your file to the IEEE, compile the file with the LaTeX, BibTeX, LaTeX, LaTeX sequence one last time and replace the two lines

```
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{IEEEabrv,IEEEexample}
```

with the contents of your `.bbl` file to obtain (in this example)

```
\documentclass[american]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}

\begin{document}
\cite{IEEEexample:article_typical}

% Generated by IEEEtran.bst, version: 1.14 (2015/08/26)
\begin{thebibliography}{1}
\providecommand{\url}[1]{#1}
\csname url@samestyle\endcsname
\providecommand{\newblock}{\relax}
\providecommand{\bibinfo}[2]{#2}
\providecommand{\BIBentrySTDinterwordspacing}{\spaceskip=0pt\relax}
\providecommand{\BIBentryALTinterwordstretchfactor}{4}
\providecommand{\BIBentryALTinterwordspacing}{\spaceskip=\fontdimen2\font plus
\BIBentryALTinterwordstretchfactor\fontdimen3\font minus
  \fontdimen4\font\relax}
\providecommand{\BIBforeignlanguage}[2]{{%
\expandafter\ifx\csname l@#1\endcsname\relax
\typeout{** WARNING: IEEEtran.bst: No hyphenation pattern has been}%
\typeout{** loaded for the language `#1'. Using the pattern for}%
\typeout{** the default language instead.}%
\else
\language=\csname l@#1\endcsname
\fi
#2}}
\providecommand{\BIBdecl}{\relax}
\BIBdecl

\bibitem{IEEEexample:article_typical}
S.~Zhang, C.~Zhu, J.~K.~O. Sin, and P.~K.~T. Mok, ``A novel ultrathin elevated
  channel low-temperature poly-{Si} {TFT},'' \emph{{IEEE} Electron Device
  Lett.}, vol.~20, pp. 569--571, Nov. 1999.

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

a document that compiles to the same output, but does not depend on external files.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you have written your references in your `ref.bib` file. Then in your original tex file, right above the `\end{document}`, add following lines;

```
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{ref}
```

I use this format in IEEE Access paper and the references are automatically designed as follows

[image: refeence]

Also, keep in mind that you should add your references in `bibtex` format to the `ref.bib` file.

Comment: Welcome to TeX:SE!

Comment: Thank you for your kindness!